# How can I use the database SQLite3 with Zeit Now (serverless)?

Tags: python, sqlite, serverless, vercel

I'm using Python.
In the directory, there is a file "main.db".

When I run the code on my computer, everything works fine.
But when I deploy to Now (serverless), reports an error:

> 502: An error occurred with your deployment
>    Type: NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_LAMBDA
>    The Lambda responsible for the path you tried to access did not reply with a 
>    status code.

And this happens, even if it is written only "import sqlite3"
I tried to register in the "requirements.txt": `sqlite3==2.6.0`, etc.
But it does not work.

How can I work with the database right in the project folder?

Comment: Answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669634/nextjs-post-api-not-working-in-live-environment-but-working-perfect-on-local/69671071#69671071

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zappa for serverless Django/Flask deployment and use [NoDB](https://github.com/Miserlou/NoDB) which stores sqlite3 into S3 and while performing any operation it loads the code and database into Lambda. You may have to set the serializer to JSON for it to be safer [read here](https://github.com/Miserlou/NoDB#warning)

This package [django-s3-sqlite](https://github.com/flipperpa/django-s3-sqlite) is also good but NoDB seems to be better for many read operations.